# How to set json data from url on highchart and polling the json data after 1 sec to dislay on highchart using Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, highcharts

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="Testscript.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myController">
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; height: 
    400px; margin: 0 auto">Time series Highchart</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Angular js code**

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?").success(function(data) {
        $scope.myData = data;


        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
                },

            series: [{
                turboThreshold: 0,
                data: data
                    }]
    });
  });
  });
```

This code is not showing the data on highchart although it is hitting the url and showing the data on console only.
I want this code to show data on highchart and also to poll data after 1 sec from url and showing it on highchart just as live data example.  http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/
OR
https://www.highcharts.com/studies/live-server.htm

Answer (score 0):

Best way of implementing that is creating (isolated scope) custom directive & passing data to it, and within directive watching changes in data provided & updating the plotted highchart with change in data. 
directive can be:

```
app.directive('chart', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div></div>',
    scope: {
        chartData: "=value"
    },
    transclude:true,
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var chartsDefaults = {
        chart: {
          renderTo: element[0],
          type: attrs.type || null,
          height: attrs.height || null,
          width: attrs.width || null
        }
        };        
        scope.$watch(function() { return scope.chartData; }, function(value) {
            if(!value) return;
            var deepCopy = true;
            var newSettings = {};
            $.extend(deepCopy, newSettings, chartsDefaults, scope.chartData);
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(newSettings);
        });
    }
  };
});
```

And you can use it in main template simply as:

```
<chart value='basicAreaChart'></chart>
```

through `basicAreaChart` you can provide all configuration options as well as data to chart directive to plot (from controller).

Working plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/ePLIPsN3S7p8OszyKzCj?p=preview

Comment: No, I don't want the chart to be updated through random data but only through data it is getting through url.

Comment: For that just create angular service to make http get request then in controller have it like $scope.basicAreaChart.series[0].data = dataService.getData() . But again this will run only once so if you want to load data live then you've to add this code inside interval e.g. $interval(updateData, 1000); where updateData is the function where you call service and update chart data property